# How to create a wordcloud without removing the punctuations in the text?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, word-cloud

I am trying to create a word cloud in in python. My goal is to have the words in the csv file appear as they are, without the removal of any punctuations. i have tried several approaches, but I am not sure how to do this. Currently, the code I am using removes the punctuations. How can I create the wordcloud without removing the punctuations.

The data that I have is a one-column data in csv format like this (header is CONTENT3).

```
CONTENT3
NumVeh:SV
Driver_age:25-44
Rd_desc:straightflat
Weather:clear
NumVeh:SV
Weather:clear
```

The code I used is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS


comment_words = ''
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
 
# iterate through the csv file
for val in df1.CONTENT3:
     
    # typecaste each val to string
    val = str(val)
 
    # split the value
    tokens = val
    tokens = val.split()
     
    # Converts each token into lowercase
    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        tokens[i] = tokens[i].lower()
     
    comment_words += " ".join(tokens)+" "
 
wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 2000, height = 2000,
                random_state=1, background_color='white', colormap='Set2', collocations=True,
                stopwords = stopwords,
                min_font_size = 10).generate(comment_words)
 
# plot the WordCloud image                      
plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8), facecolor = None)
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout(pad = 0)
 
plt.show()
```

The result is below. Although the underscores appear, the colons and other punctuations are automatically removed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to deal with this. I created a dictionary using the words and their frequencies. Then, I plotted the wordcloud using the 'generate_from_frequencies' approach. The wordcloud was created with the punctuations as needed.